# How to search for string patterns in another string and include a separator?

Tags: r, string

My data is structured as follows:

```
dput(head(CharacterAnalysis,5))
structure(list(Character = c("A", "a", "B", "b", "C"), 
Descriptor = c("Jog", "Change Direction", "Shuffle", "Walk", "Stop"), 
.Names = c("Character", "Descriptor"), 
row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I wish to lookup the `Character` and relevant `Descriptor` in the following data frame, but am unsure how to do so:

```
dput(head(StringAnalysis,3))
structure(list(MovementString = c("ACb", "aAaB", "BbCa"), 
.Names = c("MovementString"), 
row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

My expected outcome/ data frame would be:

```
dput(head(Output,3))
structure(list(MovementString = c("ACb", "aAaB", "BbCa"), 
MovementPerformed = c("Jog/ Stop/ Walk", "Change Direction/ Jog/ Change Direction/ Shuffle", "Shuffle/ Walk/ Stop/ Change Direction")
.Names = c("MovementString", "MovementPerformed"), 
row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like a forward stroke (/) or similar to separate each `Descriptor` as it signals a new movement. Any advice on how to please complete this? My data frame `CharacterAnalysis` is over 1 million rows long, so I do not wish to have to search for each `MovementString` separately!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CharacterAnalysis <- 
structure(list(Character = c("A", "a", "B", "b", "C"), 
Descriptor = c("Jog", "Change Direction", "Shuffle", "Walk", "Stop")),
.Names = c("Character", "Descriptor"), 
row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

Output <-
structure(list(MovementString = c("ACb", "aAaB", "BbCa"), 
MovementPerformed = c("Jog/ Stop/ Walk", "Change Direction/ Jog/ Change Direction/ Shuffle", "Shuffle/ Walk/ Stop/ Change Direction")),
.Names = c("MovementString", "MovementPerformed"), 
row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

# A simple approach based on names

# Build the lookup table just once
m <- CharacterAnalysis$Descriptor
names(m) <- CharacterAnalysis$Character

# Build the MovementPerformed column
Output$MovementPerformed <-
   sapply(strsplit(Output$MovementString,""), 
          FUN = function(x) paste(m[x], collapse = "/ "))
```